# word ladder in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a word ladder program in python. I'd like to generate words that are similar to a given word. In c++ or java, I would go through each valid index in the original string, and replace it with each letter in the english alphabet, and see if the result is a valid word. for example (pseudocode)

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
  for (every character c in the alphabet) {
    change the letter of word at index i to be c. 
    if the result is a valid word, store it in a list of similar words
  }
}
```

.

However, this doesn't seem like a very "python" way of doing things. How would I approach this problem in python?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you want, but wouldn't calculating the edit distance between the word and all the words in the dictionary to find similar words suit your needs better?

Comment: It would if I was looking for efficiency, but I'm just doing this problem for practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generator of similar words (taking a predicate, i.e. a function argument which returns true or false, to check whether a word is valid) seems a reasonable first step:

```
import string

def allsimilar(word, valid):
  wl = list(word)
  for i, c in enumerate(wl):
    for x in string.ascii_lowercase:
      if x == c: continue
      wl[i] = x
      nw = ''.join(wl)
      if valid(nw): yield nw
    wl[i] = c
```

If you want the list, `list(allsimilar(word, valid))` will of course build it for you.

Alternatively, you could omit `wl` and build the new word directly as

```
nw = word[:i] + x + word[i+1:]
```

but, without having timed it carefully, I suspect that might be slower.

One small possible optimization would be to also `import array` and then use

```
  wl = array.array('c', word)
```

instead of `list(word)`.